# What is the name of this electrical schematic symbol?

Tags: symbol

[image]

I don't know what is this symbol.

Comment: It looks like a DIAC symbol.

Comment: it appears to be back to back SCRs

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIAC

Answer (score 2):

I see two SCRs facing opposite directions,  it's probably some sort of electronic switch or speed control.

Comment: [Anti-parallel SCR Thyristors](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=126962&part-number=AK25HB120).  Since it shows gate connection.

Comment: yes, but it shows the gates unconnected,  so either it is a representation of some more complex subcircuit or as has been suggested it is being used as a SIDAC / DIAC

Answer (score 0):

Bidirectional breakdown diode or Diac is my choice.